# Convert Ni-Mh charger's connector from cigarette lighter to USB

Tags: usb, charger, conversion, nimh

I recently purchased a very basic airpump to inflate a mattress. As we will be taking this mattress to a camping trip on a motorbike, we wont have a car cig-ligther socket (12V), only USB 5V. This is also where my question lies.

Some technicalities:
[image]

I want to convert the connector of my charger (cig lighter) to a male USB connector. I havent cracked open my charger yet, but I assume it has some sort of a buck converter in it, that steps down the 12V (cig lighter) to 6.8V (as per datasheet the charger operates at 12V input and 6.8V at 0.25A output).

With the conversion to USB, I would have an input of 5V and as such my charger wouldn't have to step down anymore, rather step up. Without having looked at the insides of the charger, I assume its a buck-converter only, hence it wont be able to step up (boost) to 6.8V and as such charge at 5V and ~0.35A instead of 6.8V ~0.25A.

Question:

1. Is my assumption of 5V at ~0.34A correct? (6.8V * 0.25A = 1.7W)
2. Will my chargers buck-converter just pass the 5V through as it wont be able to step it up to 6.8V?
3. Is it safe/recommended to charge 4x1.2V 1500mAh with 5V/0.34A?
4. Alternatively, should I just get rid of the insides of the charger and use 5V from the USB socket directly? I assume the pump itself has a PCB that draws around 1.7W so 5V should be fine?

Operation manual (again...very basic as it is a cheap pump): https://www.kmart.com.au/wcsstore/Kmart/pdfs/42721291_Manual.pdf

Bonus question:

1. in the operations manual it says charge (for 8h) and discharge 3 times fully first use to 'activate batteries' what does activating batteries mean?
2. How does my charger (without conversion, in its original state) know when my batteries are full? It comes with an LED light that glows red (pump charging) or green (pump not connected). I was assuming the charger would turn green when the batts are full, but I charged it overnight (forgot to unplug) and in the morning it was still 'red'. Doing simple maths, if it charges at 0.25A it would take 1500/250 = 6h to charge them fully, I probably charged around 15h. Is this just a very cheap charger (which I assume it is) that doesnt really care about voltage/temperature of the batteries, rather just charges very slow making sure that if you overcharge/charge for too long, it wont fry the batts?

Comment: 1. maybe, measure the output voltage. 2 it will probably drop 0.5 to 1.5v. 3. only if you monitor current and temp. 4. no, boost it to the output voltage of the orig charger. b1. basic nimh conditioning; giving the memory pleasant thoughts. b2, it doesn't, it's an aggressive trickle charger from the description.

Comment: @dandavis so in order to charge it from the 5V USB I'd need to use a boost converter and boost it to 6.8V (this would however allow me to scrap the cig light charger, which basically uses the buck converter). Or, I attach the original charger directly to the battery, changing the cig light connector to two individual lugs for pos and neg terminals, which is 12V. Do you agree?

Comment: those are both fine options. I would recommend a boost using a chip made by XL semi; best low-end DC-DC chipsets in terms of efficiency and frequency.

Comment: Why are you limited to USB?   There are 12V output portable powerbanks.   Or you could probably series connect two 5V powerbanks and get 10V...your pump charger would likely be quite happy with that.    What about this motorbike... Doesn't it have a 12V battery????

Comment: @KyleB it does, but its a rental motorbike and I dont want to fiddle around with it too much. I assume the battery is not very accessible. Furthermore, I dont want to charge while stationary, risk of draining the battery. And in order to charge while riding it has to be wired/installed properly. Again its a rental motorbike... not ideal for DIY projects. But it comes with USB outlet, that is 5V (afaik). I have a powerbank, I will check the output voltage on that, good hint. But I assumed they are also 5V as its all USB ports.

Comment: @KyleB oh lol indeed, my powerbank has an output of ~9-12V so I can just change the connector of my cig lighter to USB and use my powerbank as charger:).

Comment: NiMH have some memory that requires initializing the double layer charge chemistry for full capacity